# Не запускается сервер mongo

Tags: mongodb

Не с того не с сего сервер стал отказывать мне в доступе.

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Ввожу данную команду,вроде пишет что процесс запустился,но если прописать дальше status,работа сервера все продолжает быть остановленной.

Вот такое дело в логах

```
2016-01-03T00:54:41.222+0600 F JOURNAL  [initandlisten] dbexception during recovery: 13544 recover error couldn't open /var/lib/mongodb/journal/j._0
2016-01-03T00:54:41.242+0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 13544 recover error couldn't open /var/lib/mongodb/journal/j._0, terminating

2016-01-03T00:54:41.242+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting

2016-01-03T00:54:41.242+0600 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...

2016-01-03T00:54:41.242+0600 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2016-01-03T00:54:41.242+0600 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2016-01-03T00:54:41.242+0600 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2016-01-03T00:54:41.242+0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2016-01-03T00:54:41.242+0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2016-01-03T00:54:41.242+0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2016-01-03T00:54:41.242+0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2016-01-03T00:54:41.242+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было найдено.
Каким то образом файл определенной базы данных с расширением .ns испортился,не знаю из за чего,но думаю,что часто делал удаление базы. Нужно его удалить из папки и перезапустить сервер,предварительно можно удалить папку journal. По крайней мере данные действия мне помогли

Comment: recover error couldn't open /var/lib/mongodb/journal/j._0

Действия помогли, но @kff был прав